# Which is the best IDE for Angular2/Typescript For Windows

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, code-editor

I have `VSCode` and `Brackets` installed, however I was wondering are there any editors available which can provide me code snippet suggestions like Eclipse or NetBeans?

I mean There must be some plugins or extensions for few editors by what I'll be able to generate a `small skeletons for classes,services,directives` in angular2/typescript.

Any ideas?

Comment: SO is not a tool recommendation website that's why I'm voting to close the question. As a piece of advice though, just try them out and see which one fits you best.

Comment: @toskv Why not move these kind of questions to a suitable place, if there is one?

Answer (score 4):

Webstorm IDE,
it happens to support all major frameworks, right now.
It has syntax hilighting, inbuilt vcs, code review, build system, **snippets** etc.
[checkout Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)
Its developed by jetbrains.

Comment: Webstorm all the way, By far the only IDE having support for angular RC. Has anyone intergrated Codelyzer into webstorm tslinting?

Comment: Visual Studio Code is also awesome, especially with Angular Essentials plugin.